# Trigger Malfunction in SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, view, triggers

I have a trigger which calls a view referencing another database if it exist:

```
if EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = 'mydb' OR name = 'db'))
    begin
        //call view referencing another database
    end 
    else
    begin          
        //do something
    end
```

The View's inner query goes like

```
Select Col from mydb2..tab1
```

While debugging I sometimes face a problem i.e if the database does not exist the app throws an exception of table not exist as well as running on sql gives the same error.

It gets resolved sometimes by restarting sql service or iis but is not a permanent solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd describe any trigger that attempts to access resources outside of its own database as broken, full stop. *Why* does your trigger attempt to access another database? Look for another solution would be my advice.

Comment: the trigger attempts to update a table with values from another product or module referencing its own